# android - How can I return 5 String arrays in doInBackground?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to return 5 string arrays from doInBackground that can be used by postExecute.

I can't seem to find an answer for this.

Thanks for help :D

Comment: wrap them in a object or a list?

Comment: wrap them in an object?

Comment: how did you solve, wrapper or string array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as such

```
public class AASync extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, ArrayList<String[]>> {

    private ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String[]> doInBackground(String[]... params) {
        for(int i=0; i<params.length;i++){
            list.add(params[i]);
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String[]> strings) {
        super.onPostExecute(strings);
        list = strings;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply wrap what ever you want in List
and also you can extend the AsyncTask and create as much properties as you whant

Comment: I found this before, http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Wrapper.html but is this what I need?

Comment: This class is an actual usage of the wrapper pattern for JDBC classes.

Comment: so no just use it like that 
`ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
result.add(str1);... etc
return result;`

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String[]>> {

    private ArrayList<String[]> someArrayString= new ArrayList<String[]>();
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String[]> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            someArrayString.add(new String[]{String.valueOf(i)});
        return someArrayString;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String[]> params){
        super.onPostExecute(params);
         //...
    }
}
```